# JFileChooser showSaveDialog multiple occurrence

Tags: java

Good day to all.

I have a problem regarding JFileChooser's showSaveDialog.

This segment of code is used for exporting CSV files and converting it into a (.XLS) file. Here's a segment of my code:

During execution, whenever I click ExportButton, open the JFileChooser, I am able to choose on what directory I may save my converted file. Once selected, the JTextField beside the JFileChooser gets the desired location where my file would be saved.

EDIT: Code is fixed already! Thanks for helping me! :)

```
else if(e.getSource() == ExportButton){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    selection5 = new JTextField(20);
    selection5.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(200));
    selection5.setText("");

    panel.add(SaveButtonCSVFile);

    panel.add(selection5);
    boolean panelChecker = false;
    while(panelChecker == false){
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Quesion",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        switch (result) {
            case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
            if(selection5.getText().trim().length() == 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please input valid filename");
                selection5.setText("");
            }
            else{
                if(selection5.getText().trim().contains(".xls")){
                     panelChecker = true;
                     exportFilename = selection5.getText().trim();
                      ....(other code)
                     exportFilename = null;
                     selection5.setText("");
                 }
                 else{
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please append .xls to your filename");
                 }
             }
             break;

             case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                  panelChecker = true;
             break;
             }
       }
}
else if (e.getSource() == SaveButtonCSVFile) {
       int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(DataUI.this);
       String temp = selection5.getText().trim();
       if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          selection5.setText("");
          File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
          String suffix = ".xls";
          if(file.getAbsolutePath().contains(".xls")){
              suffix = "";
          }
          selection5.setText(file.getAbsolutePath() + suffix);
        } else {
            selection5.setText(temp);
          }
    }
```

My problem is, if i click again the ExportButton to export my data, it opens the JFileChooser again, and repeating this process, I was able to understand the pattern it makes:

1st click of Export result to 1 time open of JFileChooser, 2nd click of Export results to 2 times open of JFileChooser, 3rd click of Export results to3 times open of JFileChooser, and so on.

How can I make the JFileChooser to open only once?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are you calling `showSaveDialog` somewhere else in your code? Can you create the shortest possible click handler that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thank you for responding!
no i am not calling it somewhere else. it's only within that segment of code under actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the `ActionListener` `this` to the `SaveButtonCSVFile` each time you press the `ExportButton`

```
SaveButtonCSVFile.addActionListener(this);
```

So, the first time your press the `ExportButton`, `SaveButtonCSVFile` will have one `ActionListener`, the second time, it will have two, then three ... and soon on...

This is one of the reasons I prefer to create a custom inner class with all the components I need already added to it.  Creating a new instance as required (or maintaining a single reference which can be re-used)